# Cassandra Error "./bin/nodetool decommission"

Tags: cassandra

My cassandra cluster's ring is following.

```
    Address         DC          Rack        Status State   Load            Effective-Ownership Token                                       
                                                                                           159798937583215624764598934804025953415     
172.16.228.113  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  79.93 KB        37.41%              53308554391200048212055997923356692434      
172.16.228.111  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  27.74 MB        7.20%               65566706948329075554413307447708030255      
172.16.228.112  datacenter1 rack1       Up     Normal  49.17 MB        55.38%              159798937583215624764598934804025953415
```

I want to reboot one node due to maintenance.
So I try to execute "./bin/nodetool -h localhost decommission".

After any minutes passed, I got following error message on "system.log".
I did not get response for "decommission" command, so I finished the process with "CTRL + C".

```
ERROR [Thread-18] 2012-11-23 11:23:29,249 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 135) Exception in thread Thread[Thread-18,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ThreadPoolExecutor has shut down
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor$1.rejectedExecution(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:816)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.receive(MessagingService.java:566)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:113)
ERROR [Thread-5] 2012-11-23 11:23:29,251 AbstractCassandraDaemon.java (line 135) Exception in thread Thread[Thread-5,5,main]
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: ThreadPoolExecutor has shut down
    at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor$1.rejectedExecution(DebuggableThreadPoolExecutor.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:816)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1337)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.receive(MessagingService.java:566)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessage(IncomingTcpConnection.java:155)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:113)
```

What is mean this message, and please give me solution.

Comment: This is very serious problem for me...

Comment: If you just want to reboot a node, decommission is the wrong action. You should run `nodetool disablethrift`, `nodetool disablegossip`, `nodetool drain`, and then stop the Cassandra process (either by killing it or something like `service cassandra stop`. Decommission takes the node completely out of the ring which is unnecessary if you just want to reboot the node.